# Rails: model validations and errors not appearing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating multiple objects from a single form:

```
def new
  @opening_hour = []
  7.times do
    @opening_hour << OpeningHour.new
  end
  render :template => "stores/opening_hours/new"
end

def create
  params["opening_hour = "].each do |hour|
    if hour["day"] != "" || hour["closes"] != "" || hour["opens"] != ""
      @res = OpeningHour.new(opening_hour_params(hour))
      puts @res.errors unless @res.save
       redirect_to(store_items_index_path)
       return
    end
  end
end
```

and the form looks like this:

```
<%= form_tag store_opening_hours_create_path do %>
  <% @opening_hour.each do |hour| %>
    <%= fields_for 'opening_hour = []', hour do |p|%>
  <% if @res.errors.any? %>
    <div class="centerList">
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(@res.errors.count, "error") %> <%= t 'store_edit_account_errors' %></h2>
        <% @res.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

But after I click on submit... I get an error: `undefined method 'errors' for nil:NilClass` at this line `<% if @res.errors.any? %>`. If I delete the error part from the form then everything works fine and the all 7 objects get created.  From my understanding this is happening because the value @res is nil... but not really sure how to make this work... any ideas??

**Update 1**

```
def new
  @opening_hour = []
  7.times do
    @opening_hour << OpeningHour.new
  end
  render :template => "stores/opening_hours/new"
end

def create
  params["opening_hour = "].each do |hour|
    if hour["day"] != "" || hour["closes"] != "" || hour["opens"] != ""
      @res = OpeningHour.new(opening_hour_params(hour))

      if @res.success
      format.html { redirect_to @res, notice: 'Hours were successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @res }
      else
        format.html { render :'stores/opening_hours/edit' }
        format.json { render json: @res.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try instantiating it at the top of the `create` action. Probably it's not getting set as you think it is.

```
def create
  @res = OpeningHour.new
  # ...
end
```

You should also have to do something similar in the `new` action, `@res` is also not set there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Iceman... I'm already setting the `@res` inside my create action! I tried your solution, the page loads without an error this time but when I click on submit the validation errors don't appear inside the form! Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Also, if I keep my code according to how I had it and not update1.. when I debug it the `@res.errors`inside my create method  returns error values, thus its not nil... but why its not showing on the actual form I don't know!

Comment: You're setting it inside a loop yes, are you sure the loop is actually running, that is what I meant.

Comment: If I delete the code regarding the errors from my form, then yes I can create all 7 items successfully. So yes I guess the loop is running, or at least I think it is, if this is what you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

If you redirect, you trigger a new request where everything that happens before in memory is not persisted.

This is the reason why:

- on success we redirect: everything went fine
- on error, we render the form directly so it has the object with errors to display

Comment: Thanks for the reply @apneadiving... I update the question with what you are suggesting but I'm still receiving the same error `undefined method 'errors' for nil:NilClass`... maybe I got something wrong here!

Comment: Also, if I keep my code according to how I had it and not update1.. when I debug it the `@res.errors`inside my create method  returns error values, thus its not nil... but why its not showing on the actual form I don't know!

Comment: because you have to render the same partial, you also have to rely on the same instance variables, beware :)